# Understanding Type of `flip ($)`

Tags: haskell

Looking at the type of `($)` and `flip`:

```
ghci> :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b

ghci> :t flip
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

Can you please explain to me how `flip ($)` has such a signature?

```
ghci> :t flip ($)
flip ($) :: b -> (b -> c) -> c
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pretty simple really:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
       |______|    |    |
           |       |    |
flip  ::  (a    -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

Hence we are essentially unifying `(a -> b -> c)` with `(a -> b) -> a -> b`. For the sake of clarity let's rename `(a -> b -> c)` to `(r -> s -> t)`:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
       |______|    |    |
           |       |    |
flip  ::  (r    -> s -> t) -> s -> r -> t
```

Hence:

1. `r` unifies with `(a -> b)`.
2. `s` unifies with `a`.
3. `t` unifies with `b`.

Therefore:

```
flip ($) :: s -> r -> t
         :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

This is equivalent to:

```
flip ($) :: b -> (b -> c) -> c
```

That's all that there is to it.

---

**Edit:**

1. The `flip` function has one argument, `(a -> b -> c)`, and one return value `b -> a -> c`.
2. When you write `flip ($)`, the `($)` function becomes the first argument of the `flip` function.
3. Hence the type signature of `($)` is [unified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) with the type signature of the argument of `flip`.
4. Unification is the process of combining two terms into one term.
5. In this case the two terms are `(a -> b -> c)` and `(a -> b) -> a -> b`.
6. To unify them into one term `(a -> b -> c)` is first renamed to `(r -> s -> t)` and then `r` is substituted for `(a -> b)`, `s` is substituted for `a` and `t` is substituted for `b`.

For example, we could write a Prolog program to  unify terms:

```
% fun(R, fun(S, T))         is equivalent to (r -> s -> t).
% fun(fun(A, B), fun(A, B)) is equivalent to (a -> b) -> a -> b.

?- fun(R, fun(S, T)) = fun(fun(A, B), fun(A, B)).
R = fun(A, B),
S = A,
T = B.
```

A unification algorithm can be found here: http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse5

To summarize the unification algorithm, when unifying `term1` and `term2`:

1. If `term1` and `term2` are constants then they unify if and only if they are the the same constant. For example `Int` only unifies with the constant `Int`. It doesn't unify with the constant `Char`.
2. If `term1` is a variable and `term2` is a non-variable then `term1` is instantiated to `term2` (i.e. `term1 := term2`). Example, `a` and `Int` unify with `a := Int`.
3. If `term2` is a variable and `term1` is a non-variable then `term2` is instantiated to `term1` (i.e. `term2 := term1`). Example, `Int` and `b` unify with `b := Int`.
4. If `term1` and `term2` are both variables then they are both instantiated to one another and they are said to share values (i.e. `term1 := term2` and `term2 := term1`). For example, `a` and `b`, when unified, become the same variable.
5. If `term1` and `term2` are complex terms (e.g. `term1` is `Either a Int` and `term2` is `Either Char b`), then they unify if and only if:

   1. They have the same type constructor. For example, `Maybe Int` and `Maybe Char` have the same type constructor. However, `Maybe Int` and `[Int]` do not.
   2. Their corresponding arguments unify. For example in `Either a Int` and `Either Char b`, the arguments unify with `a := Char` and `b := Int`.
   3. The variable instantiations are compatible. For example, when unifying `Either a a` with `Either Char Int`, we first have `a := Char` and then `a := Int`. This is incompatible. Hence the two terms do not unify.
6. Two terms unify if and only if it follows from the previous 5 clauses that they unify.

Comment: How did you know that (a -> b) gets applied to flip's first argument, a?

Comment: I edited my answer. The first and only argument of `flip` is `(a -> b -> c)`. It's not that `(a -> b)` gets applied to `a`. It's more like `(a -> b -> c)` gets unified with `(a -> b) -> a -> b`. Hence `a` is unified with `(a -> b)`.

Comment: Great diagrams.  Unclear how helpful giving the algorithm is, but I guess it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 4):

Line up corresponding components of the types:

```
($)  ::  (a -> b) -> a -> b
flip :: (a        -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

Important rule: in any type signature, you can replace every occurrence of a type variable with another that doesn't appear anywhere in the same signature, and get a type that is completely equivalent to the original.  (Types don't care about the names of the type variables, only which variables are equal and which are different within the same signature.)  So we can rename type variables slightly in `flip` (`a := x`, `b := y`, `c := z`) and it's the same type:

```
($)  ::  (a -> b) -> a -> b
flip :: (x        -> y -> z) -> y -> x -> z
```

Slightly different rule: in any type signature, we can replace all instances of a type variable with *any type* and get a **specialized** version of that type.  Let's specialize `flip` to the type that makes it compatible with `($)`.  We do that by replacing `x := (a -> b)`, `y := a` and `z := b`:

```
($)   ::  (a -> b) -> a -> b
 flip :: ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

Now that the type of the first argument of this specialized version of `flip` matches the type of `($)`, we can figure out the type of `flip ($)`:

```
 flip ($) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

Now we replace `b := c`, and after that, `a := b`:

```
 flip ($) :: b -> (b -> c) -> c
```

Answer (score 2):

Unflipped `$` gets a value of type `a` on its right side and applies it to the function `(a -> b)` from its left side:  `func $ value` is the same as `func value`.

Flipped `$` takes a value of type `b` on its left side and applies the function `(b->c)` from its right side to it: `` value `flip ($)` func `` is the same as `func value`.