# What is happening when I compose * with + in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, function-composition

I'm trying to understand the result of

```
(*) . (+)
```

in Haskell. I know that the composition operator is just the standard composition of mathematical functions- so

```
(f . g) = f (g x)
```

But:

```
(*) . (+) :: (Num (a -> a), Num a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

I'm struggling to understand this type signature. I would have expected to be able to do things like:

```
((*) . (+)) 1 2 :: Num a => a -> a
= (* (+ 1 2))
```

What is the meaning of (*) . (+)'s type signature? I tried playing with it by something like (just matching up with its signature):

```
((*) . (+)) 1 (\x -> x + 1) 1
```

But that fails to compile. I'm trying to walk through the logical steps when composing these, but I'm not fully understanding how it's getting to this result (and what the result *is*).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I understand how you feel. I found function composition to be quite difficult to grasp at first too. What helped me grok the matter were type signatures. Consider:

```hs
(*) :: Num x => x -> x -> x
(+) :: Num y => y -> y -> y
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Now when you write `(*) . (+)` it is actually the same as `(.) (*) (+)` (i.e. `(*)` is the first argument to `(.)` and `(+)` is the second argument to `(.)`):

```hs
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
       |______|    |______|
           |           |
          (*)         (+)
```

Hence the type signature of `(*)` (i.e. `Num x => x -> x -> x`) unifies with `b -> c`:

```hs
(*) :: Num x => x -> x -> x -- remember that `x ->  x -> x`
                |    |____| -- is implicitly `x -> (x -> x)`
                |       |
                b ->    c

(.) (*) ::          (a -> b) -> a ->    c
                          |             |
                          |          |‾‾‾‾|
           Num x =>       x          x -> x

(.) (*) :: Num x => (a -> x) -> a -> x -> x
```

Hence the type signature of `(+)` (i.e. `Num y => y -> y -> y`) unifies with `Num x => a -> x`:

```hs
(+) :: Num y => y -> y -> y -- remember that `y ->  y -> y`
                |    |____| -- is implicitly `y -> (y -> y)`
                |       |
       Num x => a ->    x

(.) (*) (+) ::  Num x                => a ->     x    ->    x
                                        |        |          |
                                        |     |‾‾‾‾|     |‾‾‾‾|
                              Num y  => y     y -> y     y -> y

(.) (*) (+) :: (Num (y -> y), Num y) => y -> (y -> y) -> y -> y
```

I hope that clarifies where the `Num (y -> y)` and `Num y` come from. You are left with a very weird function of the type `(Num (y -> y), Num y) => y -> (y -> y) -> y -> y`.

What makes it so weird is that it expects both `y` and `y -> y` to be instances of `Num`. It's understandable that `y` should be an instance of `Num`, but how `y -> y`? Making `y -> y` an instance of `Num` seems illogical. That can't be correct.

However, it makes sense when you look at what function composition actually does:

```hs
( f  .  g ) = \z ->  f  ( g  z)

((*) . (+)) = \z -> (*) ((+) z)
```

So you have a function `\z -> (*) ((+) z)`. Hence `z` must clearly be an instance of `Num` because `(+)` is applied to it. Thus the type of `\z -> (*) ((+) z)` is `Num t => t -> ...` where `...` is the type of `(*) ((+) z)`, which we will find out in a moment.

Therefore `((+) z)` is of the type `Num t => t -> t` because it requires one more number. However, before it is applied to another number, `(*)` is applied to it.

Hence `(*)` expects `((+) z)` to be an instance of `Num`, which is why `t -> t` is expected to be an instance of `Num`. Thus the `...` is replaced by `(t -> t) -> t -> t` and the constraint `Num (t -> t)` is added, resulting in the type `(Num (t -> t), Num t) => t -> (t -> t) -> t -> t`.

The way you really want to combine `(*)` and `(+)` is using `(.:)`:

```hs
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
f .: g = \x y -> f (g x y)
```

Hence `(*) .: (+)` is the same as `\x y -> (*) ((+) x y)`. Now two arguments are given to `(+)` ensuring that `((+) x y)` is indeed just `Num t => t` and not `Num t => t -> t`.

Hence `((*) .: (+)) 2 3 5` is `(*) ((+) 2 3) 5` which is `(*) 5 5` which is `25`, which I believe is what you want.

Note that `f .: g` can also be written as `(f .) . g`, and `(.:)` can also be defined as `(.:) = (.) . (.)`. You can read more about it here:

[What does (f .) . g mean in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279306/783743)

Comment: Thank you for your expansive reply. I'm trying to step through each part of it and understand. At one point you mention `(.) (*) ::          (a -> b) -> a ->    c`, which becomes `Num x => (a -> x) -> a -> x -> x`. Where does the extra `x` come from? Why does `c` become `x -> x`, and not just `x`?

Comment: @user2666425 The function arrow is right associative. This means that functions of the type `f :: a -> b -> c` are *more explicitly* of the type `f :: a -> (b -> c)`. This follows the intuition that `f` is a function which takes one argument of the type `a` and returns another function `g :: b -> c`, which in turn takes one argument of the type `b` and returns a value of the type `c`. Hence when we unify `(*) :: Num x => x -> x -> x` with `b -> c` we are naturally unifying `Num x => x -> (x -> x)` with `b -> c`. Thus `b` unifies with `x` and `c` unifies with `x -> x`. Hope that helps. =)

Comment: If you want to understand how unification works, then this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27117861/783743

Comment: @AaditMShah Ahhhh, I see. So this does imply that Haskell is forming closures all the time behind the scenes when we make multi-argument functions? In that, if we have `f :: a -> b -> c`, this really makes a closure `g :: b -> c` that has 'captured' the argument a? Or is this not considered a closure?

Comment: It is indeed a closure. However, unlike in languages like JavaScript where the closure can modify its upvalues, in Haskell `g :: b -> c` cannot modify the value of `a` because Haskell is pure. Hence the concept of closures in Haskell is not really that important. Closures are only important when we have mutable upvalues. However, values in Haskell are immutable. Hence, I would say it's not really as much about closures as it is about lexical scoping.

Comment: I was able to make sense of the type of the composition -- but I want this to be very explicit: why doesn't it _compile_? I think it doesn't compile because `(a -> a)` isn't an instance of `Num`. Correct?

Comment: @senderle yes. Defining `Prelude> let f a b c = ((*) . (+)) a b c` at GHCi prompt is OK, but trying to use `f` brings about the error message that says as much.

Comment: @bjb568 Perhaps this fiddle will help you understand the problem and the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/shte9qs4/

Comment: @user2666425, technically, a closure is not a *language feature* but an *implementation technique*. Anonymous functions are, in many contexts, implemented using closures, but if a multiple-argument Haskell function is applied to all its arguments, no intermediate closures will actually be allocated.

Answer (score 9):

`(*)` and `(+)` both have the type signature `Num a => a -> a -> a`
Now, if you compose them, you get something funky.

```
(*) . (+) :: (Num (a -> a), Num a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

That's because `(*)` and `(+)` are expecting two 'arguments'.

(+) with one argument gets you a function. The `.` operator expects that function (the `a -> a` that you see).

Here's the meaning of `(*) . (+)`

```
                                       x     f          y
 (*) . (+) :: (Num (a -> a), Num a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

`(*) . (+)` maps `x f y` to `((x +) * f) y` where `f` is a function from `a` to `a` that is ALSO a number.
The reason `(*)` expects a function is to make the types match while it expects two arguments, but that function has to be a number because `(*)` only works on numbers.

Really, this function makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 7):

Some extensions first:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, TypeSynonymInstances #-}
```

As the other answers show, your function is

```
weird :: (Num (a -> a), Num a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
weird x g = (x +) * g
```

But this function does have non-weird semantics.

There is a notion of [difference lists](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Difference_list). Accordingly, there is a notion of difference integers. I've seen them being used only in the dependently typed setting (e.g. [here](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2011/003424.html), but that's not the only case). The relevant part of the definition is

```
instance Enum DiffInt where
    toEnum   n = (n +)
    fromEnum n = n 0

instance Num DiffInt where
    n + m = n . m
    n * m = foldr (+) id $ replicate (fromEnum n) m
```

This doesn't make much sense in Haskell, but can be useful with dependent types.

Now we can write

```
test :: DiffInt
test = toEnum 3 * toEnum 4
```

Or

```
test :: DiffInt
test = weird 3 (toEnum 4)
```

In both the cases `fromEnum test == 12`.

**EDIT**

It's possible to avoid the using of the `TypeSynonymInstances` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances #-}

weird :: (Num (a -> a), Num a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
weird x g = (x +) * g

instance (Enum a, Num a) => Enum (a -> a) where
    toEnum   n = (toEnum n +)
    fromEnum n = fromEnum $ n (toEnum 0)

instance (Enum a, Num a) => Num (a -> a) where
    n + m = n . m
    n * m = foldr (+) id $ replicate (fromEnum n) m

type DiffInt = Int -> Int
```

As before we can write

```
test' :: DiffInt
test' = weird 3 (toEnum 4)
```

But now we can also write

```
-- difference ints over difference ints
type DiffDiffInt = DiffInt -> DiffInt

test'' :: DiffDiffInt
test'' = weird (toEnum 3) (toEnum (toEnum 4))
```

And

```
main = print $ fromEnum $ fromEnum test'
```

prints `12`.

**EDIT2** Better links added.

Comment: Are we to assume `newtype DiffInt = DiffInt { getDiffInt :: Int -> Int }`?

Comment: Also, the minimal complete definition of `Num` is: `(+), (*), abs, signum, fromInteger, (negate | (-))`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num

Comment: @Aadit M Shah, the code [compiles](http://ideone.com/OFdpK0). I know about the minimal complete definition of `Num`, that's why I'm said "the relevant part".

Comment: Plus, `weird` doesn't return a `DiffInt` (unless `DiffInt` is a `type` synonym and not a `newtype`, in which case you run the risk of the following problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26824138/783743).

Comment: It's a good answer and I'll definitely upvote it because it's something new.

Comment: Yes, your code compiles and runs but I see that you are making `DiffInt` a type synonym for `Int -> Int`. As a general rule, it's not a good idea to make instances of type synonyms. It's especially a bad idea to make type synonyms an instance of `Num`.

Comment: @Aadit M Shah, I edited the answer, but this is still a bad idea. Even worse probably, since the definition is much wider and less clear now.

Comment: Indeed. However, any new idea is good (even if it is bad) just because it is a new idea. An idea is better than no idea. Hence compared to the other answers (mine included), I think you deserved the +1.

Answer (score 2):

Let:

```
m = (*)
a = (+)
```

then

```
(m.a) x = (m (a x)) = m (a x)
```

Now `m` expects a `Num a` as a parameter, on the other hand `(a x)` , i.e. `(x +)` is a unary function `(a -> a)` by definition of `(+)`. I guess what happened is that GHC tries to unite these two types so that, if you have a type that is both a number and a unary function, `m` can take a number and a unary function and return a unary function, since they are considered the same type.

As @Syd pointed, this unification wouldn't make sense for any normal number types such as integers and floating point numbers.

Answer (score 2):

There are good answers here, but let me quickly point out a few steps where you went wrong.

First, the correct definition of function composition is

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```

you omitted the `x` on the LHS.  Next, you should remember that in Haskell `h x y` is the same as `(h x) y`. So, contrary to what you expected,

```
((*) . (+)) 1 2 = (((*) . (+)) 1) 2 = ((*) ((+) 1)) 2 = ((+) 1) * 2,
```

and now you see why that fails. Also,

```
((*) . (+)) 1 (\x -> x + 1) 1
```

does not work, because the constraint `Num (Int -> Int)` is not satisfied.