# How does fmap fmap apply to functions (as arguments)?

Tags: function, haskell, types, functor, function-composition

I am trying to understand how `fmap fmap` applies to a function like say `(*3)`.

The type of `fmap fmap`:

```
(fmap fmap):: (Functor f1, Functor f) => f (a -> b) -> f (f1 a -> f1 b)
```

Type of `(*3)`:

```
(*3) :: Num a => a -> a
```

Which means that the signature `a -> a` corresponds to `f (a -> b)`, right?

```
Prelude> :t (fmap fmap (*3))
(fmap fmap (*3)):: (Num (a -> b), Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I have tried creating a simple test:

```
test :: (Functor f) => f (a -> b) -> Bool 
test f = True
```

And feeding `(*3)` into it, but I get:

```
*Main> :t (test (*3))

<interactive>:1:8:
    No instance for (Num (a0 -> b0)) arising from a use of ‘*’
    In the first argument of ‘test’, namely ‘(* 3)’
    In the expression: (test (* 3))
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: `Num a => a -> a` and `f (x -> y)` do not align well, you end up with `f ~ (->) a` and `a ~ x -> y`, hence `Num (x -> y)`.  A more interesting one might be `fmap ($ [1, 2, 3]) $ fmap fmap $ fmap (+) $ Just 10`, which returns `Just [11,12,13]`.  A more useful `Functor` combinator might be `fmap fmap fmap`, which lets you just list a function through two different `Functor`s:  `(.:) = fmap fmap fmap`; `(10*) .: [Just 1, Nothing, Just 3] == [Just 10, Nothing, Just 30]`

Comment: Note that `fmap fmap fmap` is equivalent to `fmap . fmap` since the outer functor is forced to be `(->) (a -> b)` (which is why asking for the type of `fmap fmap fmap` only specifies two functors in its constraints).

Comment: But why does `(fmap fmap (*3))` typecheck? I guess I am just with ghci difference in handling two functions with the argument of the same type (`(fmap fmap (*3))` and `test (*3)`)

Comment: `fmap fmap fmap` looks really weird

Comment: `test (*3)` produces a type error because the type variables `a` and `b` are not present in the output type. Since there is a `Num (a -> b)` constraint, this constraint must be resolved when this function is applied (because it cannot be resolved later). Since no such instance exists, you get a type error at that moment. Change it to `test :: (Functor f) => f (a -> b) -> (a,b)` and you will get `test (*3) :: Num (a -> b) => (a, b)`.

Answer (score 5):

Polymorphism is dangerous when you do not know what you are doing. Both `fmap` and `(*)` are polymorphic functions and using them blindly can lead to very confusing (and possibly incorrect) code. I  have answered a similar question before:

[What is happening when I compose * with + in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27664213/783743)

In such cases, I believe that looking at the types of values can help you figure out where you are going wrong and how to rectify the problem. Let's start with the type signature of `fmap`:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
                     |______|    |________|
                         |            |
                      domain      codomain
```

The type signature of `fmap` is easy to understand. It lifts a function from `a` to `b` into the context of a functor, whatever that functor may be (e.g. list, maybe, either, etc.).

The words "domain" and "codomain" just mean "input" and "output" respectively. Anyway, let's see what happens when we apply `fmap` to `fmap`:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
                     |______|
                         |
                       fmap :: Functor g => (x -> y) -> g x -> g y
                                            |______|    |________|
                                                |            |
                                                a    ->      b
```

As you can see, `a := x -> y` and `b := g x -> g y`. In addition, the `Functor g` constraint is added. This gives us the type signature of `fmap fmap`:

```
fmap fmap :: (Functor f, Functor g) => f (x -> y) -> f (g x -> g y)
```

So, what does `fmap fmap` do? The first `fmap` has lifted the second `fmap` into the context of a functor `f`. Let's say that `f` is `Maybe`. Hence, on specializing:

```
fmap fmap :: Functor g => Maybe (x -> y) -> Maybe (g x -> g y)
```

Hence `fmap fmap` must be applied to a `Maybe` value with a function inside it. What `fmap fmap` does is that it lifts the function inside the `Maybe` value into the context of another functor `g`. Let's say that `g` is `[]`. Hence, on specializing:

```
fmap fmap :: Maybe (x -> y) -> Maybe ([x] -> [y])
```

If we apply `fmap fmap` to `Nothing` then we get `Nothing`. However, if we apply it to `Just (+1)` then we get a function that increments every number of a list, wrapped in a `Just` constructor (i.e. we get `Just (fmap (+1))`).

However, `fmap fmap` is more general. What it actually does it that it looks inside a functor `f` (whatever `f` may be) and lifts the function(s) inside `f` into the context of another functor `g`.

So far so good. So what's the problem? The problem is when you apply `fmap fmap` to `(*3)`. This is stupid and dangerous, like drinking and driving. Let me tell you why it's stupid and dangerous. Take a look at the type signature of `(*3)`:

```
(*3) :: Num a => a -> a
```

When you apply `fmap fmap` to `(*3)` then the functor `f` is specialized to `(->) r` (i.e. a function). A function is a valid functor. The `fmap` function for `(->) r` is simply function composition. Hence, the type of `fmap fmap` on specializing is:

```
fmap fmap :: Functor g => (r -> x -> y) -> r -> g x -> g y

-- or

(.)  fmap :: Functor g => (r -> x -> y) -> r -> g x -> g y
                          |___________|
                                |
                              (*3) :: Num a => a ->    a
                                               |       |
                                               |    ------
                                               |    |    |
                                               r -> x -> y
```

Do you see why it's stupid and dangerous?

1. It's stupid because you are applying a function which expects an input function with two arguments (`r -> x -> y`) to a function with only one argument, `(*3) :: Num a => a -> a`.
2. It's dangerous because the output of `(*3)` is polymorphic. Hence, the compiler doesn't tell you that you are doing something stupid. Luckily, because the output is bounded you get a type constraint `Num (x -> y)` which should indicate that you have gone wrong somewhere.

Working out the types, `r := a := x -> y`. Hence, we get the following type signature:

```
fmap . (*3) :: (Num (x -> y), Functor g) => (x -> y) -> g x -> g y
```

Let me show you why it's wrong using values:

```
  fmap . (*3)
= \x -> fmap (x * 3)
             |_____|
                |
                +--> You are trying to lift a number into the context of a functor!
```

What you really want to do is apply `fmap fmap` to `(*)`, which is a binary function:

```
(.) fmap :: Functor g => (r -> x -> y) -> r -> g x -> g y
                         |___________|
                               |
                              (*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
                                              |    |    |
                                              r -> x -> y
```

Hence, `r := x := y := a`. This gives you the type signature:

```
fmap . (*) :: (Num a, Functor g) => a -> g a -> g a
```

This makes even more sense when you see the values:

```
  fmap . (*)
= \x -> fmap (x *)
```

Hence, `fmap fmap (*) 3` is simply `fmap (3*)`.

Finally, you have the same problem with your `test` function:

```
test :: Functor f => f (a -> b) -> Bool
```

On specializing functor `f` to `(->) r` we get:

```
test :: (r -> a -> b) -> Bool
        |___________|
              |
            (*3) :: Num x => x ->    x
                             |       |
                             |    ------
                             |    |    |
                             r -> a -> b
```

Hence, `r := x := a -> b`. Thus we get type signature:

```
test (*3) :: Num (a -> b) => Bool
```

Since neither `a` nor `b` appear in the output type, the constraint `Num (a -> b)` must be resolved immediately. If `a` or `b` appeared in the output type then they could be specialized and a different instance of `Num (a -> b)` could be chosen. However, because they don't appear in the output type the compiler has to decide which instance of `Num (a -> b)` to choose immediately; and because `Num (a -> b)` is a stupid constraint which doesn't have any instance, the compiler throws an error.

If you try `test (*)` then you won't get any error, for the same reason that I mentioned above.