# Generating Infinite List in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

So, been going over some old exams in preparation for my upcoming one and came across this question:

Write Haskell code to define `ints :: [Int]` an infinite list of the following form:
`[0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4..]`

I've been plugging at it for the past half an hour but can't seem to find anything to solve it or that will do what I want. I get the feeling that what I am really wanting is a list comprehension of the form

```
ints :: [Int]
ints = [0] ++ [x (-x) | x <- [1..]]
```

But this doesn't work and I'm unsure of how to get it to work

Comment: `x` is a number, not a function...

Comment: See also the [universe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe) package, which provides `ints` under the name `universe`, and for many types, not just `Int`. The ordering for `Integer` matches the ordering given here (though not the one for `Int`); and I bet you want `Integer` anyway, since you claim you want an infinite list, which `ints` is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `x (-x)` is not of type `Int` (thanks to @leftaroundabout removed non-sense about non-valid syntax here). You want to generate two values for every `x`. So I guess the easiest way is to create lots of list pairs `[1, -1]`, `[2, -2]`, ... and then to concatenate them all together. And obviously prepend a `0`.

```
ints :: [Int]
ints = 0 : concat [[x, (-x)] | x <- [1..]]
```

Also, you might want to use `Integer` instead of `Int` as `Int` will overflow at some point but `Integer` won't.

Comment: Alternatively, with a right fold: `ints = 0 : foldr (\n ns -> n : -n : ns) [] [1 ..]`.

Comment: indeed, sticked with list comprehension as that was what OP used but actually prefer the right fold.

Comment: Or maybe `ints = 0 : ([1..] >>= \x -> [x, -x])` .

Comment: @AJFarmar Beat me to it by one minute.

Comment: @AJFarmar Ah yes, using the list monad. Nice.

Comment: Actually, `x (-x)` _is_ valid syntax, it just doesn't make much sense type-wise (since `x` has to be both a function and a number).

Comment: @leftaroundabout True; valid syntax and valid types are two *very* different things.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, it makes [some](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27665374/3237465) sense, actually.

Comment: Note that the foldr version above is basically just `concatMap (\x -> [x,-x])  [1..]` - or `[1..] >>= (\x -> [x,-x])` if you prefer infix.

Comment: Why use `concat` when you're already using a list comprehension? `ints = 0 : [v | x <- [1..], v <- [x, -x]]`

Comment: I have really appreciated all these comments. I wasn't sure what was wrong with me when trying to figure this out but I kept trying various things that were close to what you guys have provided but not quite right and the many different ways given have really shown me a lot.